# After I upgrade to PHP 5.3.0, Catalog URL Rewrites error

Tags: php, magento

After I upgrade to PHP 5.3.0, every time I try to do system index, Catalog URL Rewrites error.
Catalog URL Rewrites-Index product and categories URL rewrites  is processing over 5 days already. I cannot re-index it any more.
Every time it gives me different error messages as following. How to resolve it?

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home4/drxinghe/public_html/800choice.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 871
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home4/drxinghe/public_html/800choice.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php on line 565
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home4/drxinghe/public_html/800choice.com/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 902
```

Comment: Hey sgao88 and welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit] your question to include the relevant part of your code so the people answering your question can best help you. Thanks!

Comment: The most probably your magento hangs and it will not help. But I see that you do reindex, and 30 seconds can be not enough to finish the process. Try to increase execution time to 150 or 300 (seconds) with it: ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

Comment: Totally agree with @zhartaunik - reindexing can take a long time, and the chances are that your previous version of PHP would've had a max execution time set in php.ini to a higher value than 30 seconds (default) - this would've been overwritten when you upgraded PHP.

Comment: I do not have much knowledge about php. So should I put ini_set('max_execution_time', 300)  on top in every php file, or just one php file?  Or shall I replace every related line in every php file?

Comment: ini_set('max_execution_time', 300)  make it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If it worked before the php upgrade and not after then I would suggest that your php.ini has change the execution time during the upgrade.

If you still have the older version of the php.ini then find the value and update the newer version with it otherwise I simply update the php.ini